# Where can I trigger to update a variable in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net

My program is a 15x15 grid to schedule baseball games.

```
 Public Class Form1
    Dim aHomeTotal As Integer = 0
```

TXTaHomeTotal is the textbox under the first column that represents the number of games played in that column.

For example, the 1st column 2nd row checkbox is coded:

```
Private Sub AB_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AB.CheckedChanged
    If AB.Checked = True Then aHomeTotal = aHomeTotal + 1
    If AB.Checked = False Then aHomeTotal = aHomeTotal - 1
```

I'm having trouble figuring out where to declare that TXTaHomeTotal.Text = aHomeTotal. I'm not allowed to do it under public class and I can't use it under the text box's TextChanged event handler because that box is going to be read only. Where can I trigger this and/or what eventhandler can I use?

[image]

Comment: This is not vb6. This is vb.net. Changed tag.

Comment: all the checks in the NYY column could use the same checkchanged handler, when any of them change, blindly add/deduct one from `NYYTotal` or loop thru the 15 boxes adding a new total for each that is checked.  Also turn on Option Strict

Answer (score 1):

This is what i would do:

```
1) Create a function TotalizeColumn(int ColNum)
2) Call that function every time a checkbox is clicked with the column index
3) In the function, itinerate between all the checkboxes on that column ans sumarize checked ones and totalize checks into a variable.
4) Set text for TXTaHomeTotal.Text with variable from point 3.
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

ericpap's Solution is a nice way.

What I like to do when having to update a lot of Elements, is working with a `Timer` with a interval of, say 100ms. This is especially useful if you have different Elements in a form that Need to be updated.

Implement it like so;

```
Public Sub UpdateTimer_Tick(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles UpdateTimer.Tick 
    TXTaHomeTotal.Text = aHomeTotal
    TXTaHomeTotal.Refresh 
    ...
End Sub
```